# libcurl, handle chunked data

Tags: c, ftp, libcurl, chunked

I'm using libcurl in C to get list of files in the directory:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, path);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_fwrite);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, data);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

In the callback I'm parsing the output and processing the files:

```
static size_t my_fwrite(void * buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * root)
{
    ftp_user_data * data = (ftp_user_data *)root;

    char * rec = bxi_malloc(size * nmemb + 1);
    bxi_memcpy(rec, buffer, size * nmemb);

    printf("### %u (%u*%u)\n", (u32)(size*nmemb), (u32)size, (u32)nmemb);
    lines_process(rec, data);

    bxi_free(rec);

    return size * nmemb;
}
```

But I have a problem. If the directory is big enough, the answer comes back chunked:

```
### 2865 (1*2865)
## 
drwxr-xr-x   2 film     tk           4096 Jun  6 10:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 114 film     tk          53248 Jun 21 19:02 ..
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       19944333271 Jun  6 04:01 00f94595-a72c-44d7-8d7a-990c04a96f90
-rw-r--r--   3 film     tk        3439134 Jun  6 01:01 049307a7-b335-4981-a77c-735628473343
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       138285646 Jun  6 01:20 075a6aa4-8eab-43cc-9262-04f19ce11c6a
<...>
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       2712631246 Jun  6 00:41 61043b6f-6897-499a-8ca3-8c3d2401af10
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       2459646286 Jun  6 01:14 6afd69e4-b098-453a-ae4f-790e3f08fff0
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       2401778628 Jun  6 01:17 75ade815-1138-4db7-b096-49f945996e8f
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       32681128626 Jun  6 03:47 77fa0b2e-7188-4b05-9cd0-db054282885b
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       6


### 2866 (1*2866)
## 
0794406 Jun  6 01:01 78567514-d7be-4190-8951-6455f43c7bc5
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       2381291004 Jun  6 01:23 789bdabc-d893-4853-9fae-75ff9b3e9d95
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       863532650 Jun  6 00:51 7e58294b-4ce0-4a21-8829-aa7b3c0abedc
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       27817391742 Jun  6 02:57 81d72c9f-5d4b-4d54-8cb1-a108dac46ff2
-rw-r--r--   4 film     tk       21342057477 Jun  6 04:35 83e64160-03a6-400d-924a-d1848d6b85b8
<...>
-rw-r--r--   3 film     tk          16603 Jun  6 01:23 PKL_992597cf-0c66-4f57-ba34-71706ccd7e53.xml
-rw-r--r--   3 film     tk          16599 Jun  6 01:23 PKL_b32fca6b-5f36-40fb-a64f-3d110edd1b74.xml
```

This, of course, breaks the parsing algorithm in the lines_process function.

How do I ask the server or libcurl to send me data in one piece? Or is there another way to find out if the answer is chunked?

Great thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect chunked encoding can be disabled by requesting a specific HTTP version (`CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION`). And I think you can test for the presence of a 'Transfer-encoding' header. Will try to double-check and provide an example if time permits.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

As the callback of user function will be called a few times BEFORE the `curl_easy_perform` will return the control back it possible to transfer the pointer of the buffer to the my_fwrite, then *realloc* the buffer there, appending the new data, and process it only after the `curl_easy_perform` returned the control:

```
curl_easy_perform started
    my_fwrite(enter 0, appended 2000)
    my_fwrite(enter 2000, appended 2000)
    my_fwrite(enter 4000, appended 2000)
curl_easy_perform exited
postprocess the allocated buffer.
```

Great thanks to David Collins for the another solution. Unfortunately I can't apply it because the server I work with ignores the settings (NIH thing).

**UPD, the code:**

The callback data structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    char     * path;
    CML_Node * root;
    char     * lines;
} ftp_user_data;
```

The callback function:

```
static size_t my_fwrite(void * buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * root)
{
    ftp_user_data * data = (ftp_user_data *)root;

    u32 oldlen = bxi_strlen(data->lines);

    data->lines = bxi_realloc(data->lines, oldlen + size * nmemb + 1);
    bxi_memcpy(data->lines + oldlen, buffer, size * nmemb);
    data->lines[oldlen + size * nmemb] = '\0';

    printf("### %u (%u*%u)\n", (u32)(size*nmemb), (u32)size, (u32)nmemb);

    return size * nmemb;
}
```

The curl_send function, that set's the options and callback

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, path);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_fwrite); // < setting callback
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, data);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl); // < calling the curl

if (CURLE_OK != res)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error during request: %s (%d) for path %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res), res, path);

curl_easy_cleanup(curl); // < cleaning the curl

printf("Exited curl\n");

lines_process(data); // < processing stored data
bxi_free(data->lines);
```

Therefore after small answers I get:

```
### 100 (1 * 100) // < Got only 100 bytes in data->lines now
Exited curl
```

And after big answers I get:

```
### 2048 (1*2048) // < Got 2048 bytes appended to data->lines
### 2048 (1*2048) // < Now it's 2048 + 2048 = 4096 bytes
### 305 (1*305)   // < And the last 305 get appended => strlen(data->lines) == 4401
Exited curl // < now I have 4401 byte in data->lines and can totally parse it
```

Comment: would you be so kind as to post your final code here? :-)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I ask the server or libcurl to send me data in one piece?

I think the quickest and easiest way might be to specify version 1.0 of the HTTP protocol in your request. (Chunked encoding was only introduced in HTTP version 1.1.)

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
```

> Or is there another way to find out if the answer is chunked?

You can test for the presence of a 'Transfer-encoding' header and examine its value. First of all you'll need to install a header callback.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, my_header_cb);
```

Then the callback itself ...

```
static size_t my_header_cb(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                           void *userdata) {
    size_t count = size * nmemb;
    char *tok = NULL;

    tok = strtok(data, ":");
    if (!tok) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid header: %s\n", data);
        return count;
    }
    puts(tok);
    if (strcasecmp(tok, "transfer-encoding") == 0) {
        tok = strtok(NULL, ":");
        if (tok && strstr(tok, "hunked") != NULL) {
            // Set a flag or do whatever else you need here.
            printf("Using chunked encoding!\n");
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

If you wanted the callback to, e.g., set a flag to indicate that chunked encoding is being used, pass an argument to the callback.

```
int chunked_flag = 0;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, (void *)&chunked_flag);
```